# Latex formatting the plus (+) symbol as text

Tags: latex

I want to add add the '+' symbol to some of my text in Latex and am struggling to format it correctly. I want the end result to be "Hello+", and to look just like plain text

Just `Hello+` results in
[image]
which doesn't look quite right

while `Hello{\LARGE\texttt{+}}` results in
[image: 'Hello+' using texttt]
with the plus symbol too high vertically (The LARGE was used to approximately match the font size)

Comment: If the vertical position is the only problem, you could use `\raisebox{-0.5ex}{...}` to lower it (adjust the value to fit your needs)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand which layout you are aiming for, but if you just want to move it further down, you can use

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

Hello\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}

\end{document}
```

(adjust the value of `-0.5ex` as needed)